# how to create trigger events in two view model

Tags: c#, wpf

I was just wondering if it's possible to create a trigger event from one view model to another view model. If so how can this be achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Tecnically it is possible - you can use  Events for example for it. But the other question - is it really what you need?

ViewModel work together with View or Views. The next stage is the communication between ViewModel and Model etc..

To answer your question - yes it is possible, but most likely it will be not the best practice of sowtware development.